# Criteria for simulating joining tables without mapping association

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables representing `Class1` and `Class2`, with a common column which is `sharedUuid`. I want to retrieve all entries from `Class1` whose column `sharedUuid` is not equal to any entry in `Class2`. So, if for example `sharedUuid` is a country and `class1` contains entries with 'Spain', 'USA', and 'France' and `Class2` 'USA' and 'France' then I should be retrieving just Spain. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong because I am getting all of them. Thanks.

```
DetachedCriteria criteriaUuid = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Class2.class);
criteriaUuid.setProjection(Property.forName("sharedUuid"));

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Class1.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Property.forName("sharedUuid").in(criteriaUuid)));

return hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Comment: If you run it with show-sql on, what does it produce?

Comment: You want to select entries from Class1, but the Criteria you execute is for Class2. Also, I would use property.notIn().

Comment: I just changed it. I had put the classes in the wrong order. The use of notIn does not change anything. The sql looks like: "select class1 from Class1 where sharedUuid not in (select shareUuid from Class2)". It looks ok to me.